# mock of autowired field is null in unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

Does anyone know why in this example, when running "ATest", I get a null on the line "return b.getBAutoWiredObject().getString();"

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {
    @Mock
    private A a;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        String testedString = a.method();

        assertEquals("blah", testedString);
    }   
}

@Service("A")
public class A {
    public String method() {
        B b = new B();

        return b.getBAutoWiredObject().getString();
    }
}

@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Bautowire")
    private BAutoWiredObject bAutoWiredObject;

    public BAutoWiredObject getBAutoWiredObject() {
        return bAutoWiredObject;
    }
}

@Service("Bautowire")
public class BAutoWiredObject {
    private String string = new String("blah");

    public void getString() {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the answer would be it's `null` because you created the `B` instance yourself. **Spring is not involved in the least**, so it hasn't autowired anything.

**In this case**, your `A` object is a `@Mock` and mocks are typically implemented to return `null` in any method that has a return type that is a reference type. **Your `method()` implementation isn't actually getting called. The mock's implementation is.**

<sub>This is all assuming your test would actually compile and was valid with a `@Test` annotated method.</sub>

---

```
assertEquals(testedString, "blah");
```

should be

```
assertEquals("blah", testedString);
```

The first argument should be the expected value and the second should be the actual value.

Comment: yes you're right, that assert line was incorrect, I didn't pay attention to that because it's not the focus of my question.

So what would I have to do to allow my mocked "A" object be able to go down the hierarchy and get the string from the "BAutoWiredObject"?

Comment: @MacAttack You wouldn't. If you're testing `A`, you shouldn't be mocking it. If you're doing some integration testing and mocking `A`, then it doesn't matter if `A'`s code is run, you should instead be setting expectations.

Comment: Could this be solved with a when()? ie. I added B as a mock object in my test class and then did when(B.getBAutoWiredObject().getString()).thenReturn("blah");

Comment: @MacAttack No, **`A` is mocked.** So don't expect your `A` class to be involved. Maybe you shouldn't be mocking `A`. In any case, Spring is not involved at all in your tests. You should change that.

Comment: fixed the example to be more accurate.

Comment: @MacAttack One of the points I'm trying to make is that, currently, you could remove all the Spring annotations and your test would run the exact same way. You should look into `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `@Configuration` classes. There's too much to cover here about how to test with Spring. My answer simply explains the behavior you are seeing.